# Calculate k-running average of an array in OCaml

Tags: list, recursion, functional-programming, ocaml, average

I am attempting to create a function in OCaml that gives the "k-average" of consecutive elements in a list. For example:

```
 average 4 [1; 2; 3; 4; 5; 6] = [2; 3; 4]
```

since the average of 1, 2, 3, 4 is 2, of 2, 3, 4, 5 is 3, and of 3, 4, 5, 6 is 4.

I have created a function that averages the list, but with every 2 elements:

```
 let rec average2 xs = match xs with
 | [] -> []
 | x :: [] -> [x]
 | x :: x' :: xs -> if xs = [] then [(x + x') / 2] else [(x + x') / 2] @ 
 (average2 (x'::xs))
```

How can I modify this to allow me to average k-elements?

Comment: Instead of writing`x :: x' :: xs -> if xs = [] ...` you can write `[x; x'] -> ...` or `x :: x' :: [] -> ...`, *(both are equivalent)* and create a third pattern to your matching : `x :: x' :: xs`, here `xs` won't be empty by construction of the pattern matching.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you should do is just verify that the list has the proper length and then two recursive functions will do it easily :

```
let average n l =
  if List.length l < n then failwith "List is too small"
  else
    (* this function computes one k-average and returns the result *)
    let rec aux2 acc i = function
      | hd :: tl when i < n -> aux2 (acc + hd) (i + 1) tl 
      | _ -> acc / n

    in 
    let rec aux acc l = match l with
      (* the resulting list is reversed *) 
      | [] -> List.rev acc
      | _ :: tl -> 
        (* Get the k-average of the k first elements of the list *)
        let avgn = aux2 0 0 l in
        (* if the rest of the list is too small, we reached the
           end for sure, end *)
        if List.length tl < n then List.rev (avgn :: acc)
        (* recursive call on the rest of the list (without the head) *)
        else aux (avgn :: acc) tl
    in aux [] l
```